# Nested Ajax.Actionlink(InsertionMode.insertafter causing some mess)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, partial-views

I have 3 view in my application(1 main , 1 partial , 1 nested partial) and i used to call partial(from main) and nested partial(from partial) again and again

- ActionLink used at main view

  ```
  <div id="newPackage">@Ajax.ActionLink("Create New Package", "createPackage", "test",
  new AjaxOptions
      {
          InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
          HttpMethod = "post",
          UpdateTargetId = "newPackage"
      })</div>`
  ```

  **Flow of this actionlink**:: When i click this link(again and again) then new partail view(createPackage) is added after id="newPackage" on every click
- ActionLink Used inside createPackage partial view(view rendered after click on link from main view)

  ```
     <div id="newCheck">
     @Ajax.ActionLink("add Checks", "addAnotherCheck", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, UpdateTargetId = "newCheck" })<br/><br/></div>
  ```

  **Flow of this ActionLink**::When i click this link(again and again) then new nested partail view(addAnotherCheck) is added after id="newPackage" on every click

  i.e Main objective is to create multiple packages with each package hold multiple checks
  Done with everything(all my work is done and my app(ASP >NET MVC3) is working fine)
  Problem is( in view only) when i try to create multiple packages with multiple checks then clicking on "add check" link from package2,3..n view(of nested partial)(excluding 1) another "addAnotherCheck" nested view is appending after package1 "add check" link
  but i need it to append after calling "add check"
  **In a nutt shell**::calling nested partial again and again(from partial(that to i am calling again and again from main view)) with ajax.actionlink(with insertionmode.InsertAfter) that is inserting that nested partial to 1st partial only.

Answer (score 0):

InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter is looking for an HTML element ID.  These should be unique on your page.  Once you add a "newCheck" ID, then MVC Ajax is finding the first one.  What you really need to do is put a placeholder at the end and use InsertionMode.InsertBefore.  So your view would look something like this:

```
<div id="newPackage">...
<div id="newCheck" />
```

Then remove the id="newCheck" from your partial view.  Now your markup from your partial view will always be placed just above the div with the newCheck ID which will always be at the bottom of your page.

Your resutling HTML should look somethig like this:

```
<div id="newPackage">...
<div> @Ajax.ActionLink("add Checks", "addAnotherCheck", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore, UpdateTargetId = "newCheck" })<br/><br/></div>
<div> @Ajax.ActionLink("add Checks", "addAnotherCheck", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore, UpdateTargetId = "newCheck" })<br/><br/></div>
<div> @Ajax.ActionLink("add Checks", "addAnotherCheck", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore, UpdateTargetId = "newCheck" })<br/><br/></div>
<div> @Ajax.ActionLink("add Checks", "addAnotherCheck", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore, UpdateTargetId = "newCheck" })<br/><br/></div>
<div id="newCheck" />
```

That should work and now you won't have any more duplicate IDs in your HTML either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code is inserting several divs with the same id: your partial view always adds `<div id='newCheck'>...</div>`, so the page ends up full of divs with the same id.

- First, this is not legal. An HTML document shouldn't have more than one element with the same ID.
- Second, when you click `"addAnotherCheck"` only the first element with the `UpdateTargetId` is found (because it's supposed to only be one element with the same ID). So the check is always inserted after the firs one. As this is not allowed, every browser could do different things.

So, you should change the ID whenever you render the same partial in the same page. You could simply add something random after the id, and use the same id for the div and the `UpdateTargetId`. The obvious random thing which can be safely used is a `Guid`. For this case, a timestamp would also work.